# How is Cost Per Share calculated in Report Builder 3?

Tags: reporting

Unsure how the cost per share is calculated for an entire account.  I've tried taking the Total Cost Basis / Billing Market Value, but that did not produce the same number that is showing.  I've tried adding up all of the cost per shares for the lots held within the account and divided by the number of lots, but that also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Cost per share or "Cost Basis Per Unit" is calculated as the Cost Basis (with or without amortization based on settings) divided by the number of units in the lot.